# Stats on categorical variables

Tags: statistics, categorical-data, minitab

I have 2 groups in my analysis. I have coded some lab results as 1 = bacterial colonies are red 2 = bacterial colonies are dark and shiny and 3 = bacterial colonies are black and rough. I would like to do some sort of statistical analysis on these so that I can tell if there is a significant difference between the numbers I have recorded for one group compared to the other, but the columns are different lengths as I do not have an equal number of samples in each group. Is there any tests anyone could recommend (have been working on minitab but also happy to use prism).[image]

Comment: Interesting problem, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks! I didn't know there was a different website for stats questions. I've posted on there now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do Run test for this kind of question. Check out some more Non-Parametric Tests if you want.